# Output of grep isn't line by line

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I have this code:

```
list=$(ls -l | awk '{print$3,$6,$7,$8,$9}' | grep -v root)
echo $list
```

and the output is a joint version of all the filtered strings which looks like:

```
> avahi Nov 16 21:50 1170 syslog Nov 16 21:50 1171 messagebus ...
```

and what I wanted looks like:

```
> avahi Nov 16 21:50 1170
> syslog Nov 16 21:50 1171
> messagebus Nov 16 21:50 1179
> ...
```

I've also read that the default output of grep should give me the paragraphs version like what I want but this isn't the case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to see separate lines, just give the command: `ls -l | awk '{print$3,$6,$7,$8,$9}' | grep -v root`

Comment: Quotation marks: `echo "$list"`

Comment: Where is the `>` in the output coming from?

Comment: ALWAYS quote variables in shell scripts unless you have a good reason not to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given:

```
$ txt="line 1
> line 2
> line 3
> line 4"
```

(ie, `txt` being set to `line 1\nline 2\nline 3\nline 4`)

Consider:

```
$ echo $txt
line 1 line 2 line 3 line 4
```

vs:

```
$ echo "$txt"
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

**Use quotes** or Bash will interpret and split the whitespace (like the `\n` at the end of lines.)

Separately, it is usually [not a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to try and parse the output of `ls` since file names can have spaces in them. The spaces in the file names will break the rest of your pipe (as you have written it.)

Use a loop with a glob instead.